# Finding the area of a implicit relation

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, area

Let's say we have the function: $$x^2+y^2+\sin(4x)+\sin(4y)=4$$

I haven't taken Calculus III, in fact I'm just taking Calculus I. Since I learned how to find the derivative of implicit relations I was wondering if you can find the area of it.

Eventually I went into finding the area of closed shapes, and I found Green's Theorem.

How could you use Green's theorem to determine a contour path, use the line integral, and finally solve for the area of the closed implicit shape, such as $x^2+y^2+\sin(4x)+\sin(4y)=4$.

Is it also effective? Or could their be easier methods.

Comment: In order to use Green's theorem you have to be sure this region is closed and simply connected. Is it?

Comment: Yes it's a closed curve, and it's simply connected.

Comment: @MarkFantini: [See for yourself](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) ! :-$)$

Comment: Ok so it is a closed curve, but how to you convert it into a line integral, and use greens theorem for area the function as stated.

Comment: You *need* a parametrization of the curve for calculating the line integral.

Comment: Thanks for the accept!  It actually motivated me to update my answer, as I'd thought about it a bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I offer three solutions using (as requested in your own answer) the Python's SciPy package - (1) a simple double integral technique, (2) a polar integral, and (3) a path integral using Green's theorem.  Of these, the second is certainly the best for reasons that we'll explore, the first is the easiest, and I only offer the third since it was specifically requested.  The correct value is approximately 12.711.

**A double integral**

Let $\chi$ be the characteristic function of the set.  That is,
$$\chi(x,y) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
  1 & \text{if } x^2 + y^2 + \sin(4x)+\sin(4y)<4 \\
  0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{array}\right.
$$
Then the area in question is 
$$\int_{-3}^{3} \int_{-3}^{3} \chi(x,y) \, dx \, dy.$$
The bounds for the integral can be any numbers so that the resulting rectangle contains the region of interest but (from the perspective of a numerical integrator, the smaller the better.

We can implement this in SciPy as follows:

```
from scipy import sin
from scipy.integrate import dblquad
def f(x,y): 
    if x**2 + y**2 + sin(4*x)+sin(4*y)<4:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
dblquad(f, -3,3, lambda x: -3, lambda x: 3)

#Out: (12.707523995238732, 0.0006145836908579838)
```

Thus, the area should be (approximately) $12.7075$.  The second value is an error bound, which I wouldn't trust too much, since such bounds make assumptions on the smoothness of the integrand.  In fact, a warning message is issued.  Thus, while conceptually simple and easy to program for any implicitly defined region, this technique yields a result that is not particularly reliable.  Not too surprising, as we have a multi-dimensional integrand that is discontinuous on a somewhat complicated set.

Another way to check results like this is to examine the result in another system.  This can be done with a one-liner in Mathematica:

```
NIntegrate[Boole[x^2 + y^2 + Sin[4x] + Sin[4y] < 4], {x,-3,3}, {y,-3,3}]
(* Out: 12.6825 *)
```

The result differs significantly but, again, a warning message is issued and the result should be considered suspect.

**A polar integral**

Another approach is to use the polar expression for area:
$$\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} \frac{1}{2} f(\theta)^2 \, d\theta,$$
where $\alpha\leq\theta\leq\beta$ and (for a given $\theta$) $0\leq r\leq f(\theta)$.  In our case, $\theta$ runs from $0$ to $2\pi$ and, given a $\theta$, we must determine the distance of the corresponding point on the boundary of our region.

[image]

The radius $f(\theta)$ can be computed fairly easily for this region using a numerical equation solver; we are fortunate that the region displays sufficient regularity to allow this.  This scheme can be implemented in SciPy as follows:

```
from scipy import sin, cos, pi
from scipy.optimize import brentq
from scipy.integrate import quad
def f(r,theta): return (r*cos(theta))**2 + (r*sin(theta))**2 + 
  sin(4*r*cos(theta))+sin(4*r*sin(theta)) - 4
def rr(theta): return brentq(lambda r: f(r,theta),1,3)
def integrand(theta): return 0.5*rr(theta)**2
quad(integrand, 0, 2*pi)

#Out: (12.710967450506423, 7.130808983545281e-08)
```

Note that there is no message issued and the error estimate is much better.  Not surprising, as we have an easily computed, continuous, one-dimensional integrand.  Also, it's easily implemented in Mathematica:

```
f[theta_?NumericQ] := r /. FindRoot[
  (r*Cos[theta])^2 + (r*Sin[theta])^2 + 
    Sin[4 r*Cos[theta]] + Sin[4 r*Sin[theta]] == 4, 
  {r, 1, 3}];
NIntegrate[f[theta]^2/2, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}] 
(* Out: 12.710967451423258 *)
```

The difference between the two systems is on the order of $10^{-10}$.  The one disadvantage of this approach is that it is not very broadly applicable as the region needs to be amenable to a polar description.

**Green's theorem**

Finally, you can use Green's theorem as you propose.  While the integral is one dimensional, the only way to parametrize the boundary is to use interpolation.  Then, you're stuck computing a numerical derivative of the interpolation in the integrand, which leads to it's own problems.

At any rate, the idea behind this approach arises from Green's theorem

$$
\iint_{\Omega} \left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right) \, dA
=
\oint_{\partial\Omega} P \, dx + Q \, dy
$$
with $Q(x,y)=x$ and $P(x,y)=0$ we get
$$\iint_{\Omega} 1 \, dA = \oint_{\partial\Omega} x \, dy.$$
Now, the integral on the left clearly represents the area of $\Omega$ and the integral on the right can be easily computed as
$$\oint_{\partial\Omega} x \, dy = \int_a^b x(t)y'(t)\,dt,$$
*if* we have a parametrization $(x(t),y(t))$ of the boundary of $\Omega$.  We can get that parametrization using interpolation.

To implement this in SciPy, first we'll generate an image of the region.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x,y): return x**2 + y**2 + np.sin(4*x) + np.sin(4*y)
delta = 0.01
x = np.arange(-3,3,delta)
y = np.arange(-3,3,delta)
x,y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
z = f(x,y)
contour_pic = plt.contour(x,y,z,[4])
```

Calling `plt.show()` should generate the following image.

[image]

Now, we need the points in the image for interpolation.

```
xy = contour_pic.collections[0].get_paths()[0].vertices
```

The interpolation goes as follows

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
t = np.linspace(0,1,xy.shape[0])
fx = interp1d(t,xy[:,0], fill_value=xy[0,0], bounds_error=False, kind='cubic')
fy = interp1d(t,xy[:,1], fill_value=xy[0,1], bounds_error=False, kind='cubic')
```

With these points, we can now compute the integral.

```
from scipy.misc import derivative
from scipy.integrate import quad

def integrand(t): return fy(t)*derivative(fx,t,0.002)
quad(integrand, 0,1)

# Out: (12.675772468194559, 0.05846541344794076)
```

The result does not look particularly close to the previous results, we have a poor error bound, and a warning message is issued.  None of this is surprising, as the integrand is much more complicated than the polar version.

Comment: Thank you for the update! I have been looking into irregular closed shapes such as $x^2+y^2+sin(4xy)=4$. I believe this is difficult to apply to a polar description.

Comment: I've been trying to use parametrization by taking your polar description and multiplying it by $\cos(t)$ and $\sin(t)$. From there I could use parametrization.

Comment: @Arbuja Yes, I can see that would be difficult, as $r$ is not uniquely defined as a function of $\theta$. For what it's worth, the Mathematica command `RegionMeasure[DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + Sin[4 x*y] < 4.1, {{x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}}],MaxCellMeasure -> 0.00001]]`, which did very well with the first example, returns 12.9066.

Comment: Where and how did you exactly learn computer programming? Did you take any courses, or online from any tutorials? I am almost near college and can perhaps take a course.

Answer (score 0):

Being a topic of 8 years ago with already a very detailed answer, I certainly don't have the ambition to write innovative things, it's to be understood as a corollary that could be useful to someone.

---

**Wolfram Mathematica 13.0**

Quite simply, by writing:

```
NIntegrate[Boole[x^2 + y^2 + Sin[4 x] + Sin[4 y] < 4], 
           {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
```

> 12.7111

that being a result without warnings is probably close to that exact (better to deepen).

---

**Monte Carlo method**

The basic idea is to bombard with `10^n` balls the square of area $A_q$ which encloses the region of plane `D` of interest which goes from vertex `(-3,-3)` to vertex `(3,3)` and to count the `m` balls that also fall internally to `D`. The area of `D` is therefore estimated by $A_q\,m/10^n$. It goes without saying that a good *pseudorandom real number generator* is crucial here:

```
Table[m = 0; Do[{x, y} = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, 2];
      If[x^2 + y^2 + Sin[4 x] + Sin[4 y] < 4, ++m], {10^n}];
      36. m / 10^n, {n, 7}]
```

> {14.4, 14.4, 12.636, 12.6972, 12.776, 12.6944, 12.7077}

or more efficiently:

```
Table[{x, y} = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {2, 10^n}];
      36. Total@Boole@Thread[x^2 + y^2 + Sin[4 x] + Sin[4 y] < 4] / 10^n, {n, 8}]
```

> {7.2, 12.24, 13.536, 12.708, 12.7224, 12.7193, 12.7109, 12.7112}

The calculated area is the better the larger it's `n`.

---

**Discrete Fourier Transform + Gauss-Green theorem**

First, I tabulate *the coordinates of some points of the boundary* proceeding counterclockwise:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2 + Sin[4 x] + Sin[4 y]

pts = ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 4, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
                  PlotPoints -> 100][[1, 1, 1]];
```

Through *Discrete Fourier Transform*, I determine a *trigonometric fit of least squares* to the data:

```
TrigFit[v_, m_, {x_, x0_, x1_}] := Module[{fc, fs, i, imax, j, n, t},
  n = Length[v]; imax = Min[m, Floor[(n - 1) / 2]]; t = 2 π (x - x0)/(x1 - x0);
  fc = Table[Sum[v[[j + 1]] Cos[2 π i j / n] / n, {j, 0, n - 1}], {i, 0, imax}];
  fs = Table[Sum[v[[j + 1]] Sin[2 π i j / n] / n, {j, 0, n - 1}], {i, 0, imax}];
  fc[[1]] + 2 Sum[fc[[i + 1]] Cos[i t] + fs[[i + 1]] Sin[i t], {i, 1, imax}]]

{x[t_], y[t_]} = TrigFit[pts, 100, {t, 0, 2 π}];
```

Finally, I *calculate the area enclosed* by this parametric curve using the *Gauss-Green theorem*:

```
NIntegrate[x[t] y'[t], {t, 0, 2 π}]
```

> 12.7106

If you want to check, it's also possible to *superimpose the implicit curve on the parametric one*:

```
Show[ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]],
     ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 4, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 100]]
```

[image]

where it's evident that they overlap perfectly, so the calculated area is very close to the exact one!

---

About the case mentioned in the comments `x^2 + y^2 + Sin[4 x y] < 4` it's possible to face it with the same formulations just written and the area obtained is equal to `12.6323`.